# Cannot run C++ code on the newly installed Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I have done the following to try to set up development environment for C++ on macOS but in vain.

1. I downloaded Visual Studio Code from Microsoft website and correctly installed.
2. I installed ms-vscode.cpptools and mitaki28.vscode-clang.
3. I installed gdb.

The following is the warning I got:

> ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/andy/Documents/VS Code C++/Hello World/.vscode/tasks.json, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x7B 0x0A 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x22 0x76 0x65 0x72 0x73 0x69 0x6F 0x6E 0x22 0x3A ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Users/andy/Documents/VS Code   C++/Hello World/.vscode/tasks.json

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:  
  "_main", referenced from:  
     implicit entry/start for main executable  
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64  
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

EDIT 1: My platform is macOS.

EDIT 2: My problem occurred when I was trying to build the simplest Hello World project so that the problem cannot be my C++ code. But I am almost a novice so that I have no idea what the .json things are.

EDIT 3: I think the problem may lie in launch.json file, so this is my file:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "C++ Launch (GDB)",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "targetArchitecture": "x64",
        "program": "${file}.out",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": true,
        "preLaunchTask": "g++",
        "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/local/bin/gdb"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: `0x7B 0x0A 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x22 0x76 0x65 0x72 0x73 0x69 0x6F 0x6E 0x22 0x3A -> something something 'version":'` ? That's weird. Why is it treating a JSON file as some binary object/executable file?

Comment: What OS/Platform?

Comment: Ref @paxdiablo looks like you have specified the Json file as an object file to be linked. Take a look at the build file.

Comment: You really haven't given enough information here. OS? Platform? What step are you getting the error? During install? Install of what? During build? Build of what?

Comment: The presented codes look like ASCII codes. E.g. `0x7B` is `{`. Considering that this is an `ld` error you try to link a json file. The linker expects object files and complains that the json file is no recognizable object file (what's a fact). Probably, your project setup is wrong. Btw. IMHO this is no Mac OS/X specific issue. I never tried it but I'm quite sure that the linker in VS on Windows cannot link json files too.

Comment: Yes, the problem probably lies in the project setup. I used to work on VS and had no problem. When it comes to VS Code, everything just magically became more complex and I do not understand why.

Comment: As for the .json files, I just copied the code from the tutorial on the internet because I understand neither the .json files nor the code inside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you just don't have a `{somefile}.cpp` file in your project (or the file is not being compiled) containing

```
int main() {
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

or

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

function.

You can safely ignore tasks.json warning - it's being mistakenly passed to linker input and the linker just ignores the file.

Comment: I have a file named HelloWorld.cpp and have a int main() just to print Hello World.

Comment: Then it's just not being compiled for some reason. Please post full output of the building process.

Comment: The warning posted above is the full output in VS Code OUTPUT windows. In the other windows, nothings at all.

Comment: Did you use the tutorial https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp ? Significant part there is using VS Code to generate tasks.json and launch.json files.

Comment: Thank you, that works!!! But there is still another problem. In launch.json, I used "${workspaceRoot}/HelloWorld.cpp.out" for the program property. But I want it to be usable for other projects conveniently. What expression I can use for that purpose? Again, I appreciate for your helpful advice.

Comment: Please accept the answer then :) For the program you can use any name, for example `"${workspaceRoot}/program.out"`

Comment: Ah, in fact, I mean is there something like ${programName}.out or something else?

Comment: No, ${workspaceRootFolderName} seems to be the closest match https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_variable-substitution

Answer (score 1):

Same issue here, it may conflict with "Code Runner" plugin, after I remove the precompiled output, the error gone.